# Time Complexity Issues When Searching For A Duplicate

Tags: c#, time-complexity

My code returns the correct answer the first duplicate is 3. I am struggling with time complexity. Is there a more efficient way to find the first duplicate?

my constraints are 1 ≤ a.length ≤ 10^5, 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length. Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        int f = FirstDuplicate(a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static int FirstDuplicate(int[] a)
    {

        int[] answer = new int[2];
        answer[0] = -1;
        answer[1] = a.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
            for (int j = i; j < a.Length; j++)
                if (a[i] == a[j] && i != j)
                {
                    if (i < answer[1])
                    {
                        answer[0] = a[i];
                        answer[1] = j;
                        break;

                    }
                }

        return answer[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You say

> 1 ≤ a.length ≤ 105,

and

> I am struggling with time complexity. Is there a more efficient way to find the first duplicate?

Your question is nonsensical; your program is O(1) given the constraints.  **Any program where the problem size has a small bound is O(1)**.

Let's suppose we relax the condition that the length of the array is very small. In that case, plainly your method is quadratic.

There is a linear solution. It is:

```
seen = an empty set
for each element x of the array
  if seen contains x then 
    return value x
  else 
    seen = seen with x
end for
return not found
```

This is linear in the size of the array *provided that testing containment of a set and growing the set is constant time*.

Can you think of a way to make a set of integers such that checking membership in that set is constant time and adding a new member to the set is constant time?

Hint: Can you use the fact that the values in the array are small integers to your advantage?

Exercise: Now do the problem *without* any constraint on the size of the array or the size of its contents.

Exercise: Now do the problem on an arbitrary type T, where two Ts are equal if `T.Equals(T)` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few improvements you can make. Items #3, #4, and #5 will all reduce the number of iterations compared to your current code:

1. We need to actually compare the values at `a[i]` and `a[j]` to see if we've found a duplicate.
2. Store the index of `j` in a variable if it's less than the current value (which we initialize to `int.MaxValue`, so the first match will automatically get added).
3. **Add a condition to exit the loops if `i` or `j` are greater than the smallest duplicate index, because any match at that point will automatically be too large.**
4. **The outer loop only needs to go to `i < a.Length - 1` since we will be comparing it to the next value (and there is no value after `a.Length`)**
5. **The inner loop can start at `i + 1` to avoid doing comparisons of indexes we've already compared**

Here's an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the index of the first duplicate item in an array
/// </summary>
/// <param name="a">The array to search</param>
/// <returns>The index of the first duplicate item, or -1 if none exist</returns>
public static int FirstDuplicate(int[] a)
{
    if (a == null || a.Length < 2) return -1;

    var smallestDupeIndex = int.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1 && i < smallestDupeIndex; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length && j < smallestDupeIndex; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                smallestDupeIndex = j;
            }
        }
    }

    return smallestDupeIndex == int.MaxValue ? -1 : smallestDupeIndex;
}
```

Here it is in use, with an array that has many duplicates:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    Console.Write(GetFirstDupeIndex(a));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]